# Limit query results to total results minus 10 results

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

guys I cant figure this out.. I red a lot but no luck...

I have the following query, and I need to limit it in order to show the total results minus a specific number os results, let's say 10.

I mean, if the query would return 1000 total results, I want it to return 990, and the last 10 results need to be excluded.

Is this possible?

see the query call:

```
        $query = ' SELECT p.*,c.name as name_category,t.name as name_type,cy.name as name_country,s.name as name_state,l.name as name_locality,l.alias as locality_alias,pf.name as name_profile, '
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(p.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", p.id, p.alias) ELSE p.id END as Pslug,'
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(c.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", c.id, c.alias) ELSE c.id END as Cslug,'
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(cy.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", cy.id, cy.alias) ELSE cy.id END as CYslug,'
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(s.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", s.id, s.alias) ELSE s.id END as Sslug,'      
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(l.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", l.id, l.alias) ELSE l.id END as Lslug, ' 
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(t.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", t.id, t.alias) ELSE t.id END as Tslug '          
            . ' FROM #__properties_products AS p '              
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_country AS cy ON cy.id = p.cyid '               
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_state AS s ON s.id = p.sid '
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_locality AS l ON l.id = p.lid '
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_profiles AS pf ON pf.mid = p.agent_id '             
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_category AS c ON c.id = p.cid '
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_type AS t ON t.id = p.type '
            . ' WHERE p.published = 1 '         
            .' ORDER BY p.id DESC ' 
            ;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this?  What requirement are you attempting to meet?  What have you tried so far that hasn't worked?  Is there a reason you can't do this in your code instead of the query?

Comment: Could you create view and then run select on that view?

Comment: hello, the purpose is the following. this query creates a xml view that is used by real estate portals to index my properties for sale, but there is a big problem, they crawl very often my site and they are crawled by google very more often than my site, so when i search for a property or original content of my own site, in google those portals are always shown in SERP before than my site, and i think google thinks that my originalmcontent is their original content. by reducing the xml of 10 properties they will index only properties that google has already indexed in my site, got my BIG prob?

Comment: well, may I understand why the comments of the people that tried to help me where deleted?? i was trying here to inplement those hints!!! why this??????

Comment: i am not a coder, i dont know if i can do this in my code!!!!!!

Comment: there were 2 answers here that have been deleted!! I was working on their replies!! oh my God why are you doing this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, then use `limit` and `offset`:

```
limit 10, 9999999
```

This starts at the 10th record and continues to the end of the data (or to 9999999 rows, technically).

You are ordering by `p.id desc`, so this will remove the 10 rows with the highest id.

To really do what you seem want (remove the 10 with the lowest id), use a subquery and then sort again after the subquery:

```
select t.*
from (<most of your query here>
      order by p.id asc
      limit 10, 999999
     ) t
order by id desc
```

To remove the rows with the *highest* id, just add the `limit` statement:

```
    $query = 'SELECT p.*,c.name as name_category,t.name as name_type,cy.name as name_country,s.name as name_state,l.name as name_locality,l.alias as locality_alias,pf.name as name_profile, '
. ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(p.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", p.id, p.alias) ELSE p.id END as Pslug,'
. ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(c.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", c.id, c.alias) ELSE c.id END as Cslug,'
. ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(cy.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", cy.id, cy.alias) ELSE cy.id END as CYslug,'
. ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(s.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", s.id, s.alias) ELSE s.id END as Sslug,'      
. ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(l.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", l.id, l.alias) ELSE l.id END as Lslug, ' 
. ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(t.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", t.id, t.alias) ELSE t.id END as Tslug '          
        . ' FROM #__properties_products AS p '              
        . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_country AS cy ON cy.id = p.cyid '               
        . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_state AS s ON s.id = p.sid '
        . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_locality AS l ON l.id = p.lid '
        . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_profiles AS pf ON pf.mid = p.agent_id '             
        . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_category AS c ON c.id = p.cid '
        . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_type AS t ON t.id = p.type '
        . ' WHERE p.published = 1 '         
        .' ORDER BY p.id desc limit 10, 999999' 
        ;
```

Comment: hello, thanks a lot, I want to remove the rows with the highest id.. the last row that have been published... so should i use your code? can you help me and write the full query because i am not a coder? please....

Comment: Well, I didnt find any place to accept the answer... where is it?